# How to internationalize the text attribute of a TreeItem in UIBinder?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, tree, uibinder

Given a UIBinder tree like this:

```
<g:Tree ...>
    <g:TreeItem text='Links1' >
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
    <g:TreeItem text='Links2' >
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
</g:Tree>
```

How to internationalize the 'text' attribute of `TreeItem` elements (without resorting to doing it programmatically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a Messages (or Constants) interface you can do it as follows:
Add a `ui:with` resource to to UiBinder xml:

```
<ui:with field='i18n' type="com.example.myapp.client.i18n.MyMessages" />
```

Next use it as follows:

```
<g:Tree ...>
    <g:TreeItem text='{i18n.links1}' >
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
    <g:TreeItem text='{i18n.links2}' >
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
        <g:Hyperlink ... />
</g:Tree>
```

Where `links1` and `links2` refer to method names on your `MyMessages` interface.